# Creating a Spring MessageSource from Java code

Tags: java, spring

For unit test purposes I am trying to create a Spring MessageSource from Java code, but all examples and docs I can find only tell me how to do it in Spring.

Can anybody give me a hint?

The message property files are in /src/main/resources/com/neopost/cim/i18n/text/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do the following in your Java code;

```
MessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
messageSource.setBasenames(Arrays.asList("classpath:com\neopost\cim\i18n\text\message"));
```

Your message files should be named `message.properties` and must be placed inside `com\neopost\cim\i18n\text\`

`messageSource.getMessage*` methods to call and get messages.